# Хочу понять как работает эта функция (Java Script)

Tags: javascript

Найти наибольший общий делитель двух натуральных чисел:

```
function mygcd(x,y) {
  while (y !== 0) {
    y = x % (x = y);
  }
  return x;
}
```

Как работает это решение? А точнее, что происходит вот здесь: y = x % (x = y)

Answer (score 3):

```
(x = y)
```

обозначает выполнить присвоение `x = y` и вернуть итоговое значение

Тогда вот это

> ```
> y = x % (x = y);
> ```

эквивалентно такому коду

```
tmp = x % y;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```

И лучше писать именно так, чтобы потом мучительно не вспоминать, что же этот код должен делать

Comment: если писать постоянно в первом стиле - не вызывает никаких трудностей это читать(пишу так на всех МК, не вижу смысла разворачивать)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков очень хорошо, что вы не разрабатываете приложения для бизнеса, и не пишите сложную логику. Код должен быть легко читаемым и самодокументируемым. `y = x % (x = y);` - так лучше не писать в бизнес приложениях.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Пишу и то(для бизнеса) и то(сложную логику) =) может всё зависит от ЯП? естесно в JS у меня такого кода не бывает, а вот в си - всегда именно такой.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а почему в C всегда такой? Вам не жалко ваших коллег по C? Что за дискриминация по ЯП?))